# Удалить кнопку развёртывания в консоли С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Как можно заблокировать кнопку развёртывания?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы используете WinAPI, то можно вот так:

```
HWND consoleWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
DWORD consoleStyle = GetWindowLong(consoleWnd, GWL_STYLE);
consoleStyle &= ~(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
SetWindowLong(consoleWnd, GWL_STYLE, consoleStyle);
```

P.S. Не забудьте подключить Windows.h